# get through a fence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

If a dog or cat got through a fence, do they jump over a fence, or crawl through a hole in a fence, or both?

> The central dramas concern the exacting veterinary care of a
> rhinoceros in labor and the hunt for feral dogs that get through the
> fences and kill young animals.

[Cop Shoots Family Dog During 5-Year-Old's Birthday Party - HuffPost](https://%20https://www.huffpost.com/entry/cop-shoots-dog-birthday-party_n_57914634e4b0bdddc4d3e14e)

Comment: _Through_ explicitly excludes 'jumping over'.

Comment: "Got through" is a vague term for *squeezing between* a narrowing in the fence or pushing in some other way.

Answer (score 3):

Probably "crawl through a hole". Because of the word "through", it means the dog found a way to  pass the fence by going "inside it" (sort of). But obviously that isnt possible, so it found a hole and used that to crawl through and out the other side of the fence. If it jumped over the fence, I would say "the dog got **over** the fence", or you could literally just say "it jumped over the fence".